# Player not moving when adding a force

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a controller for vehicles in my game, but the vehicle won't move. I checked the input, and it is receiving input. But when I just have it add force with just `transform.foward` It does move but really slowly, but when I multiply it by the speed and `Time.deltaTime` it doesn't move at all.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TankMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //[HideInInspector]
    public float Speed = 40f;

    [SerializeField] private Transform TankHaul;
    private Vector3 Rotation;
    private Vector3 Movement;

    private Rigidbody RB;

    private void Awake()
    {
        RB = TankHaul.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    public void ProcessMovement(Vector3 Input)
    {
        Rotation.y = Input.x;

        TankHaul.Rotate(Rotation);

        Movement = transform.forward * Input.z * Speed;

        Debug.Log(Movement);

        RB.AddForce(Movement * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Time.deltaTime` represent the time between the last frame and the current one.
`Rigidbody.AddForce`, when using `ForceMode.Force`, replace the current force applied to your rigidBody.

So I think something is flawed in your reasoning. Why would you want to reduce the force by multiplying it with a small value like `Time.deltaTime` and then replace it every frame?

I think what you intend to do is add the movement vector to the tank position. This is done by `Rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + m_Input * Time.deltaTime * m_Speed)`

In your case I am not sure what Input represent and why you multiply it by transform.forward. but if input is the direction you want your tank to take, you could do : `RB.MovePosition(TankHaul.position + Input * Time.deltaTime * Speed)`